# computed property doesn't update input attribute

Tags: vue.js

I have an input field which that value of disabled is defined by a computed property.

At first, the length is the array is 0 and after the backend sends the data and initializes that array with the correct value, but it seems that after initialization it won't be updated.
Even though that in debug it seems that the reactivity does work but it doesn't update the DOM.

```
<input :disabled="isDisabled" name="header" type="checkbox">
```

and the isDisabled method as follows:

```
computed: {
  isDisabled(){
    return this.items.length === 0 ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
}
```

The items come from the props which are updated later on from the parent component:

```
props: {
  items: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:disabled` expects a `boolean`, not the string value of the actual `disabled` attribute. So:

```
isDisabled(){
  return this.items.length === 0;
}
```

... will work.

Comment: I will try the boolean even though the documentation of our input said it expects a value of 'disabled'. Could you explain the next part why is the length of the length of items?

Comment: It seems that the documentation was indeed incorrect, and you were right. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say docs are incorrect. As stated in the answer, it works with both `boolean` and `string`, because the strings are cast to booleans.  The real problem with your code was you used `this.items.length.length` instead of `this.items.length`. `this.items.length.length` will never be strictly equal to `0`. It will always be `undefined`.

Comment: Ohh that was a typo in the comment and no in the actual code, which I wondered what you meant.